# CSS to align a submit button?

Tags: css

I have a submit button on a form tag is input, obviously. Text-align obviously does not work. I don't want to use margin-left because my width might change later on and I want it to be more "proper". Any way you can think of?

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget">
```

CSS:

```
#blog_subscription-3 input[name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget"] {
   margin-left:25px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your CSS and HTML code to your question?

Comment: can you give an example off the markup off your button

Comment: And how do you want to align it?

Comment: how did you want this aligned are you talking about the text inside alignment or actually aligning the button

Comment: @DominicGreen I mean the actual button

Comment: Well... I've added a working demo so please take a look ad leave a comment! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the "top", "left", "bottom" or "right" elements. Now the html element that the button is inside of will need to be sized to allow moving it around. For example if the button is in side a of a "span" tag the "span" tag will only be the size of the button (plus any other content in the span).  As long as there is space to move it in the parent element  one of those four should do the trick.

Comment: No such thing as align:center?

Answer (score 6):

It works for me. I saw that some people forgot about `display` property.

```
#container input[type=button] 
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a common trick on css to align elements on the center.

All you got to do is, set the margins to auto.

margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center it then

```
#blog_subscription-3 input[name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget"] {
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Or

```
#blog_subscription-3 input[name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget"] {
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
```